# Primefaces Extension 11 error [...] monacoeditor.EditorOptions not present

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

Serious error when running `primefaces-extensions`. From the message, it says that `EditorOptions` is not present:

```
SEVERE: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.primefaces.extensions.model.monacoeditor.EditorOptions not present.
```

Log:

```
INFORMAÇÕES:   Loading application compras done in 17.059 ms
INFORMAÇÕES:   Using OmniFaces version 3.13
INFORMAÇÕES:   Registering WebSocket filter for url pattern /*
INFORMAÇÕES:   Initializing Soteria 1.1-b01.payara-p5 for context '/compras'
INFORMAÇÕES:   Inicializando Mojarra |version.string| para o contexto '/compras'
GRAVE:   java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.primefaces.extensions.model.monacoeditor.EditorOptions not present
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperclass(ClassRepository.java:90)
    at java.lang.Class.getGenericSuperclass(Class.java:777)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.HierarchyDiscovery.discoverFromClass(HierarchyDiscovery.java:139)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.HierarchyDiscovery.discoverTypes(HierarchyDiscovery.java:132)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.HierarchyDiscovery.discoverFromClass(HierarchyDiscovery.java:139)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.HierarchyDiscovery.discoverTypes(HierarchyDiscovery.java:113)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.HierarchyDiscovery.<init>(HierarchyDiscovery.java:94)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.HierarchyDiscovery.<init>(HierarchyDiscovery.java:87)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.enhanced.TypeClosureLazyValueHolder.computeValue(TypeClosureLazyValueHolder.java:41)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.enhanced.TypeClosureLazyValueHolder.computeValue(TypeClosureLazyValueHolder.java:31)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.LazyValueHolder.get(LazyValueHolder.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotated.getTypeClosure(BackedAnnotated.java:27)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.AnnotatedTypeValidator.validateAnnotated(AnnotatedTypeValidator.java:44)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.AnnotatedTypeValidator.validateAnnotatedType(AnnotatedTypeValidator.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getInjectionTargetFactory(BeanManagerImpl.java:1503)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.createInjectionTarget(BeanManagerImpl.java:1019)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServiceImpl.injectManagedObject(JCDIServiceImpl.java:357)
    at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider.inject(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:203)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.createInstance(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:233)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.createInstance(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:199)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.RenderKitConfigProcessor.addRenderers(RenderKitConfigProcessor.java:291)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.RenderKitConfigProcessor.process(RenderKitConfigProcessor.java:167)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.lambda$initialize$1(ConfigManager.java:341)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:318)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:5178)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:681)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5756)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:619)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:958)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:941)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:694)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1851)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1603)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:123)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:361)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.initialize(ApplicationLifecycle.java:623)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.postConstruct(ApplicationLoaderService.java:335)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:303)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:351)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:281)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:65)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2102)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:93)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:67)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.extensions.model.monacoeditor.EditorOptions
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1819)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1660)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
    ... 61 more

INFORMAÇÕES:   Running on PrimeFaces 11.0.0
INFORMAÇÕES:   Running on PrimeFaces Extensions 11.0.2
```

Has anyone already found a solution to this problem?

Primefaces 11, Primefaces extension 11.0.2, Mojarra 2.3.14, Payara 5.2021.10.

Comment: See https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions/issues/718, try with 11.0.1

Comment: @JasperdeVries, I tried version 11.0.1, but the error persists. When I used 11.0.0 it worked. A big hug!

Comment: Yeah see the ticket https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions/issues/718  its specific to Payara and the solution is posted in that ticket

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to the way Payara is scanning for classes.  For some bizarre reason Payara seems to class load where other containers such as Jboss Wildfly do not and thus do not have this issue.

See issue: https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions/issues/718

There is an EASY solution...simply include the Monaco extension in your pom.xml and then Payara will be happy.

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
   <artifactId>resources-monacoeditor</artifactId>
   <version>11.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

That will make Payara work happily again.

Comment: very good, solved the problem. Thank you very much.